# Import error while uploading app bundle to Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I have refactored my app by splitting into modules (:app, core and features). It works correctly on emulator so I decided to upload to the internal test track on Play Console but it shows an error during importation :

[image: error message]

The screencap is in french but it says basically "An error occurred during importation of Android App Bundle package. Please try again later. If the problem persists, contact Google Play assistance service for developers"

This message doesn't give any clue about what the problem is !

The previous uploaded version of this app was already an App Bundle and is currently released successfully.

The big difference between both versions is that the new one is split into modules (but no dynamic features or anything). I have added  `android:hasCode=true` to :app module manifest.

I have retried after invalidate, restart, clean, rebuild and regenerate bundle. I have retried on another day.

I have downgraded from Android Studio 3.4 to 3.3.2 (and Gradle as well) to be sure that R8 is disabled.

No luck... Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, it occurred to me that maybe I would get a more explicit message by uploading an APK instead of a Bundle.
And I did !

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
AndroidManifest.xml:63: error: ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

Because I had an @string for a intent name instead of an hardcoded string (-*shame*-)

Anyway, to be remembered : **When Bundle importation doesn't work, try uploading a simple APK to get a more explicit error message !**

Comment: Have you tried testing your App Bundle locally before uploading it to Play? And by testing, I mean deploying "APKs from app bundle", not the "Default APK" (see in the Run Configurations menu). That would have revealed the bug as well.

Comment: @Pierre Thank you for your input, i will look into that next time !